# NodeJS OSC receive and distribution to local network

Tags: node.js, sockets, osc

Hi I have this project that includes receiving real time data from a remote computer in OSC format, I want  then to be able to communicate or distribute the OSC data to other computers logged in the same network.

I am looking in NodeJS, Express, Socket.io and OSC.js; I am not sure however how this should look in terms of the structure of the communication. If I am not misunderstanding some server concepts, I need to implement a NodeJS server which will receive it and forward it trough socket.io to the local network, I am ot sure though, do I get this data by looging to the server or to some other address that broadcasts the OSC data?

Thanks

K.

Answer (score 0):

To send and receive data from an OSC server you would need to use some library as far as i know. I'm currently working with an OSC server and that was the only way i found to send so far.

Yes, you'll need to use a Node.js server.
I use [node-osc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-osc) library to host it and receive the messages, showing them on a webpage with some tricks.

To send the values you can search for libraries, but i know 3 ways:

- Arduino - there's an easy-to-use library. Usefull if you want to put some arduino board anywhere and send it through the internet.
- node-osc - the same library you use to host you can use to send messages to the server, all you have to do is write another .js file and run it in another terminal instance and voilá.
- Processing - processing is an IDE for visual stuff, not very usefull here aparently

I have a code on github here: https://github.com/georgerappel/WebServer-Node-OSC

I wrote some instructions on how to use there. The received messages will appear on console, you can see the code to understand basically what happens.

I don't know exactly how to send the message to everyone connected, it's a bit more complicated.